# How does SQL Server delayed durability work?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, documentation

I'm reading documentation for the [delayed durability feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/control-transaction-durability) of SQL Server and saw this table:

[image]

It states that database level settings always take precedence over commit level seeing. But I'm not able to understand the table.

As I understand, 2 is database level setting and 3 must be commit level setting. But why their intersection position 4 states the result is delayed durable?

Could someone help me to understand how to read this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database-level settings are DISABLED, ALLOWED, and FORCED.

The commit-level settings are ON, and OFF.

```
COMMIT WITH (DELAYED_DURABILITY=OFF)
```

is the default, and is equivalent to

```
COMMIT
```

> But why their intersection position 4 states the result is delayed durable?

The main point here is that if you set it to FORCED on the database, then all transactions execute with delayed durability.  So you switch all a database's transactions to delayed durability without changing any code.

Answer (score 2):

The leftmost column is the commit setting. The top row is the database setting. So delayed (4) is the result when commit setting of OFF (2) but the database setting (3) is forced. - [Dan Guzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman)